# Xcode and C++ error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations, Unknown type name 'module' and Expected template

Tags: c++, xcode, module, compiler-errors, gnu

I have issues using Xcode and C++. I get the error message: 'C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations', 'Unknown type name 'module'' and 'Expected template'.

Info: C++ Language Dialect is on GNU++20

Also I added a screenshot from my IDE [Screenshot from the IDE Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDpfQ.png)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
module;
export module employee;

export class Employee {
    string _first_name;
    string _last_name;
    
public:
    Employee(const string f_n, const string l_n)
    {
        _first_name = f_n;
        _last_name = l_n;
    }
    void print() const
    {
        cout << _last_name << ", " << _first_name << endl;
    }
};
```

I tried setting the C++ Language dialect to C++20 but I'd didn't helped.
I tried cleaning the build and setting it up again.
I have reseted my mac and closed and re-opened xcode.

I was expecting that those error messages are going away.

Comment: You're missing `#include <string>` and `using namespace std;` is best removed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will remove `using namesapce std` and add `#include <string>`, but this doesn't fix my problem :(

Comment: What compiler? (including version) Modules are a very new feature.

Comment: On Xcode, it's says GNU++20 [-std=gnu++20]. And then I tried C++20 [-std=c++20] but both didn't worked.

Comment: My understanding is that Xcode's **module** support for C++20 is only partially supported/implemented.  Xcode's **module** support for C++23 Standard Library is not yet implemented.

Comment: Oh, with which IDE can I work that supports module? @Eljay

Comment: My understanding is that Visual Studio 2022 support modules, when using C++20 or C++latest.  (I'm stuck on C++17, so I haven't had a chance to work with modules.  But I'm very excited about them.)